# Display data in to table by using FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

In this case, I am displaying some data from getting by the DB, in the image you can see some input fields. When I try to input some value for the input field, there have an issue when I typing the input field(Input field focusing is disabling).please help me to solve the issue.

Here is my code:(html)

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-sm" id="mytable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Item Id
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Item Name
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Quantity
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Buying Price Rs:
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Amount Rs:
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Status
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                                    Action
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr formArrayName="credentials"
                                *ngFor="let creds of grnGroup.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index">
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <b>{{creds.itemId }} </b>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <b>{{ creds.itemName }}</b>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <b>{{ creds.qty }}</b>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <!-- <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <div class="input-group-text"><b>Rs:</b></div>
                                                  </div> -->
                                        <input type="text" formControlName ="price" class="form-control" size="5"/>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <b>{{ creds.amount }}</b>
                                </td>
                                <td [formGroupName]="i" *ngIf="'Pending' == creds.status"
                                    style="color:Gold; text-align: center; ">
                                    <i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </td>
                                <td [formGroupName]="i" *ngIf="'Approved' == creds.status"
                                    style="color:green; text-align: center; ">
                                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                                        (click)="pushValue(creds[i])">
                                        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Here is the type script

```html
 ngOnInit() {
this.grnGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    credentials: this.formBuilder.array([]),
}) }

 const tableData = this.formBuilder.group({
                        itemId:[itemId] , itemName:[itemName] ,qty:[qty] , amount:[amount] ,status: [this.array[i].status] ,price:['']
                    });

   this.GRNForms.push(tableData);

  get phoneForms() {
        return this.grnGroup.get('credentials') as FormArray
      }
```

[image: Here is the Table]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: click on below link it will help you otherwise you have to put some proper code with static data or create stackblitz.

https://medium.com/@vap1231/inline-editable-table-using-dynamic-form-controls-in-angular-87eb24c0e5a5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that every time on form value changes, the reference of form value changes too, and angular redrawing the ngFor items and therefore the focus is lost

you can prevent this in two ways

1. you can add `trackBy: onTrackById` on `*ngFor`

```
*ngFor="let creds of grnGroup.controls.credentials?.value; trackBy: onTrackById; let i = index"
```

and in component.ts

```
onTrackById(index: number, item: FormGroup) {
   return index; // or unique value from {item} something like this (item.get('id').value)
}
```

2. replace `grnGroup.controls.credentials?.value` with `grnGroup.get('credentials').controls`

```
*ngFor="let creds of grnGroup.controls.credentials?.controls; trackBy: onTrackById; let i = index"
```

here is the simple example with console logs, I have reproduced what i said, Please check the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-rdg8dd

Comment: @ManojPrasanna glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pushing the new control on the form not the formArray, try this.

```
this.GRNForms.get('credentials').push(tableData);
```