# How to dynamically generate context menus in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a case where I'd like to add a context menu to each line of a generated list or table in Angular Material, something like:

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let item of itemlist">
    <mat-list-item>
        <some-component [item]="item"></some-component>
        <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>

        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <button *ngFor="let option of options" mat-menu-item (click)="fire(item, option)">
            {{ option }}
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list
```

where "`some-component`" displays whatever the `item` is, on a single line. The problem is that the menus items don't call the `fire` method when they're clicked.
My guess is that this is because the menus need their own IDs, but I can't figure out how to do that programatically. I looked at `ng-attr-id`, but couldn't figure out how to use that with the `#menu="matMenu"` syntax.
Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oenvzn) that has a more detailed example of what I'm after.

Comment: can you please share the link of edit mode?

Comment: nevermind found: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oenvzn

Comment: Apologies. Fixed the link.

Comment: actually, I have copied your code and pasted it into angular material, stackblitz example and it works, https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-overview-example.ts

Comment: maybe wrong or missed out imports?

Comment: yes I am right https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cumfvg?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: you need to import materail styles, browserAnimationModule, and MatButtonModule

Comment: check this one, I mistakenly broke the styles and can't restore https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xo4qxv?file=src/app/menu.component.html

Comment: Okay, I've determined that, in my original code, clicking on the button in the menu is not generating a click event. In fact, clicking *anywhere* in the menu appears not to generate any mouse events.

Comment: is it possible to share your code in stackblitz example?

Comment: It's in the middle of a large code base, but I'll try to isolate it.

Comment: also please check do you imported browserAnimationModue and MatButtonModule

Comment: at first `BrowserAnimationModue `

Comment: Here's an updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkybgc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233204/discussion-between-ashot-aleqsanyan-and-scott-deerwester).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the generous help of Ashot Aleqsanyan, the fix for this is to prevent the list of options from being re-rendered. The issue is that the button(s) associated with the items in the list are removed from the DOM when the list is re-rendered. One way to do this (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458307/display-data-in-to-table-by-using-formarray/59461226#59461226)) is to use the `trackBy` element of `ngFor`, like this:

```
<button
    *ngFor="let option of options; trackBy: onTrackByFunction"
    mat-menu-item (click)="fire(item, option)">
```

in the HTML, and this:

```
onTrackByFunction(index: number, item: any) {
    return index
}
```

in the Typescript.